# MapKit JS on Capacitor and Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, mapkit, capacitor

Edit: I opened a bug report with Apple - Capacitor bug report said it was Apple's problem.

Edit 2: It appears they fixed it in 5.20.3 `Fixed bug where https: was not selected for CDN URLs in some packaged and local environments. [48289622]`

I'm using MapKit JS with Ionic and Capacitor. It works fine on everything but iOS. On iOS the error occurs when attempting to download files from the CDN.

There are about 20 errors shown here where it fails to download files from the CDN:
[image]

The problem is the `capacitor://` instead of `https://`

In the downloaded `mapkit.js` file it looks like this:

```
cdnBase: "//cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk",
```

So is there anything I can do to make it load the files properly? Why does Capacitor assume `//` is a local file? Or should MapKit prefix all URLs with `https`?

I've ran into a problem with Google Maps SDK and the prefix Capacitor I think puts on `//somewebsite.com/fileNotLocal`. If the file isn't prefixed with `http` or `https` then capacitor looks locally at `capacitor://` I think

Comment: I got the same issue with Ionic 4 and Cordova (`ionic://` instead of `capacitor://`). Please report the bug at Apple if you haven't done it already (I did it already).

Comment: I also reported an issue. Also with capacitor to verify it wasn't them. I linked the Apple bug report to the Capacitor one so they didn't point the finger.